# $.ajax and hidden fields, or PHP form data?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, ajax

I'm building a lightweight admin utility using PHP and JQuery.  The purpose of the utility is to allow an admin to pull images from a database, view the tags attached to each image, and add new tags as needed.  The overall function is fairly simple, and the app works in its current form.

**My question is this**: How should information be passed back and forth between PHP to JQuery, especially given the fact that all information available to Javascript is also visible to the user on the DOM?

Currently, the program flow goes something like this: index.php queries db and retrieves info for all pics related to a certain event; the array is formatted for display in an image carousel, and also for inclusion as a hidden table at the bottom of the page (and this is what I know is wrong).  index.php requires display.html, which displays the carousel and tagging form to the user.  Whenever the user clicks the "update" button, an ajax query fires, serializing the info in the update form and sending it to updateTags.php, which performs the update query and adds the tags.

For this project I'm using [Owl Carousel](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/) with lazy load to display the images.

Here's index.php

```
<?php

// Displays picture data as HTML in order to allow javascript to traverse
// Rows are indexed using the image's location in the array, which will
// correspond to that image's location in the carousel
function FormatAsHTMLTable ($data) { 

  $dataTable = "<table id='data' class='table'><tbody>";

  foreach ($data as $i => $member) {
    $dataRow = "<tr class='" . $i . "'>";
    foreach ($member as $key => $value) {
        $dataRow .= "<td class='" . $key . "'>";
        if (is_array($value)) {
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($value as $item) {
                if (!$i++) {
                    $dataRow .= $item;
                } else {
                    $dataRow .= ", " . $item;
                }
            }
        } else {
            $dataRow .= $value;
        }
        $dataRow .= "</td>";
    }
    $dataRow .= "</tr>";
    $dataTable .= $dataRow;
  }

  $dataTable .= "</tbody></table>";

  return $dataTable;

}

function FormatAsCarouselData ($data) {

  // Formats array for display in the owl carousel

  return $carouselData;

}


// This array would normally be retrieved from a query to the mySQL db;
// this is provided as an example
$pics = array(
                array(
                    "id" => 5, 
                    "tags" => array("foo", "bar"), 
                    "url" => "img/demo-slides/owl1.jpg"
                    ), 
                array(
                    "id" => 6, 
                    "tags" => array("boo", "ya"), 
                    "url" => "img/demo-slides/owl2.jpg"
                    ), 
                array(
                    "id" => 7, 
                    "tags" => array("I", "am", "second"), 
                    "url" => "img/demo-slides/owl3.jpg"
                    ), 
                array(
                    "id" => 8, 
                    "tags" => array("bird", "is", "word"), 
                    "url" => "img/demo-slides/owl4.jpg"
                    ), 

                ...


                );

$dataTable = FormatAsHTMLTable ($pics);
$carouselData = FormatAsCarouselData ($pics);
require('display.html');

?>
```

Here's display.html, as it would look after the data table and carousel images were inserted:

```
<html>
<body>

...


<div class="row">
      <div class="col">
        <div id="imageContainer" class="owl-carousel">
          <div class='item'>
            <img class='lazyOwl' data-src='img/demo-slides/owl1.jpg' alt='Photo # 0'>                
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <img class='lazyOwl' data-src='img/demo-slides/owl2.jpg' alt='Photo # 1'>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <img class='lazyOwl' data-src='img/demo-slides/owl3.jpg' alt='Photo # 2'>
          </div>
          <div class='item'>
            <img class='lazyOwl' data-src='img/demo-slides/owl4.jpg' alt='Photo # 3'>       
          </div>

          ...

        </div>
      </div>
    <form method="post" action="lib/updateTags.php" id="updateForm">
      <div class="col">
        <input type="text" name="tag1" id="tag1" placeholder="Tag 1"/>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="tag2" id="tag2" placeholder="Tag 2"/>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="tag3" id="tag3" placeholder="Tag 3"/>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="tag4" id="tag4" placeholder="Tag 4"/>
        <br>
        <input type="text" name="tag5" id="tag5" placeholder="Tag 5"/>
        <br>
        <button type="submit" id="updateButton">Update</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <input type="hidden" id="imageIdInput" name="imageIdInput" value="">
  </form>

<table id='data' class='table' style='display:none'>
  <tbody>
    <tr class='0'>
      <td class='num'>0</td><td class='id'>5</td><td class='tags'>foo, bar</td><td class='url'>img/demo-slides/owl1.jpg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='1'>
      <td class='num'>1</td><td class='id'>6</td><td class='tags'>boo, ya</td><td class='url'>img/demo-slides/owl2.jpg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='2'>
      <td class='num'>2</td><td class='id'>7</td><td class='tags'>I, am, second</td><td class='url'>img/demo-slides/owl3.jpg</td>
    </tr>
    <tr class='3'>
      <td class='num'>3</td><td class='id'>8</td><td class='tags'>bird, is, word</td><td class='url'>img/demo-slides/owl4.jpg</td>
    </tr>

    ...

    </tbody>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

display.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var updateForm = $("#updateForm"),
      data = $("#data");

  $("#imageContainer").owlCarousel({
    items : 1,
    lazyLoad : true,
    navigation : true,
    pagination : false,
    afterMove : afterMove,
    afterInit : afterInit
  });

  owl = $("#imageContainer").data('owlCarousel');


  var form = $('#updateForm');
  form.submit(function (e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $.ajax( {
      type: "POST",
      url: form.attr( 'action' ),
      data: form.serialize(),
      success: function( response ) {
        console.log( response );
      }
    } ); 
  });


  function updateInfo(that){
    // Get the current position in the carousel
    var current = parseInt(that.owl.currentItem);

    // Get image information from data table based on carousel location
    var num = data.find("." + current).find(".num").html(),
        id = data.find("." + current).find(".id").html();

    //Display image information to user

    // update hidden form input
    imageIdInput.value=id;
    console.log("imageIdInput updated to: " + id);

  }

  function afterInit(){ // Called once the carousel is set up
    console.log("init callback called");
    var that = this;
    updateInfo(that);
  }

  function afterMove(){ // Called when the carousel moves
    console.log("Carousel moved");
    var that = this;
    updateInfo(that);

  }

});
```

So obviously, displaying all of the image info as an HTML table is the wrong way to do this.  Even though display is set to none, a quick glance at the page source will reveal all of this information.  Because this is an admin utility and will never be customer facing, this works for now; but it's amateurish and hacky.  So my question is this: **how do I provide image-specific information to JQuery, without making it entirely transparent to the user?**  Or at least, without using a separate html table?  My assumption is that it would involve a separate $.ajax call every time the carousel moves; but even so, I'm going to need to preserve some identifying information in order to know exactly which image I'm looking at.

There are a couple unique considerations for this project which are making this particularly difficult for me to figure out: 1) the image id's cannot be assumed to be sequential; thus, I can't deduce the image id from the image's position in the carousel. 2) Sometimes a subset of images is displayed to the user, rather than every relevant image; in this case, it is still necessary to let the user know where he is in relation to the full set (for instance, there might be 8000 images in the full set; the user is being shown images 1000-2000; the user must still be shown the proper image number in relation to the full set, eg "Image # 1500").

Sorry for the wall of text; I tried to exclude anything that wasn't relevant, while still making it clear what I was asking and what my current solution was.

Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: Thanks for posting on Stack Overflow. You can help us help you by shaping your question text so we can easily find the main question. Please separate it out a bit so the question is clearer. Thanks and enjoy

Comment: If you're trying to hide this information from people who have access to your admin tool, and have the know how to view source to find information, you don't want to use javascript - keep it on the server.

Comment: @Kristian, thanks! Edited to hopefully make the general question a little more clear.

Comment: @JohnnyFaldo, I thought that this might be the case.  But Javascript is going to have to maintain at least _one_ piece of identifying information on each image, otherwise there's no way to let the server know which image to edit.

Comment: @BrentKlein have left an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Upon reading your question in a bit more detail:

You could make it more difficult for the user to see this information.

It's not necessary (or efficient) to generate html content just to navigate the DOM and extract content to use as data in your Javascript - you can skip that entire step and have an AJAX call to a PHP page that returns all your image data in a nice JSON format (or however you'd like it). That would simplify your entire application, likely increase performance and also make the data harder for a user to view. That's a hat-trick!

Comment: Thanks for the answer!  To clarify, it should be efficient to load the page initially with no images, then use ajax to load the images into the carousel?  There are usually _thousands_ of images; I was afraid that putting that load on the browser would cause performance issues.  But this approach would actually work well?

Comment: Only one at a time in the carousel, and the carousel is set up to lazy load the images as they scroll into view.

Comment: So ajax them one at a time (or however many you deem reasonable)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I'm entirely sure what your question is.. but I will try to help you.

I'm guessing you want to send information about particular images from jquery -> php.. but you don't want things like the images ID etc exposed.

There are ways to accomplish this without displaying information on your DOM, but when the ajax request is made, a savvy user could still see what parameters youre sending to php looking at a developer panel.

if I wanted to make it less obvious I might store this stuff in an array in javascript..
IE..

```
/* build this array when you get your json response.  
store image name with its ID, but dont display on page. 
then when user clicks a picture you can look up the id in the array */

var elems = [{'test.jpg':1},  {'test2.jpg':2}];
```

you can also store arbitrary information in any element using jquerys data method

https://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/

You could make the image names a unique index too.  then you wouldnt even have a need to use an ID.  you'd just look up an image by it's name.  It'll be unique so you'll always get exactly one result.

don't know if this gave you any ideas because I'm still having a little trouble understanding your exact problem.

Comment: This is definitely helpful, especially the idea of constructing a javascript array containing the information.  One difference that that approach would require is pulling all images using ajax, rather than allowing the server to reload the page and push the relevant images onto the page.  Will the browser's performance start to tank when I'm using ajax to add thousands of images to the carousel on the fly?